# Not able to set unix timestamp value when day of month is before 10th

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not able to pull in correct partition value when the day of the month is before the 10th. Can someone advise the error in logic where I am assigning value to PARTITION?

```
NEW=`date +"%Y%m" --date="next month" | sed 's/ *//'`
OLD=`date +"%Y%m" --date="last month" | sed 's/ *//'`
PARTITION=`date --date="+2 month -$(($(date +"%d")-1)) days 00:00:00" +"%s"  | sed 's/ *//'`
```

The error I get is on the PARTITION declaration:

```
-bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Comment: If you are using the `date` from GNU coreutils, then just do `date +"%-d"` instead of `date +"%d"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs in the expression `$(($(date +"%d")-1))`. The `date` command returns "08" and Bash (and other shells) treat numbers with a leading zero as octal.

To force decimal representation, precede the number with `10#`.

So in your case, use `$((10#$(date +"%d")-1))`.

Answer (score 3):

k314159's answer is correct. Here is an alternate answer: do not use leading zeros in `date`'s output by specifying `%-d` instead of `%d`:

```
echo $(($(date +"%-d") - 1))
```